# How to check who called onUpdate

Tags: android, widget

i have a problem with android widget. All i have is a imagebutton in the layout. if the user presses the button some operation (changing a boolean value) in background via a service is done and it works perfectly. now i need an alarmmanager to check every 5 minutes the status of the boolean value (maybe another user has changed it. This also works but i can not differ if the service was called by button (to change the value) or by alarmmanager (to check the value).

Are there any flags i can set, e.g. to the alarmmanager? Does anyone hav any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use intent extras in the intent that you send when button has been pressed, to indicate that it was from button press.